# How to shift internal communication of nodes in a MongoDB cluster to another network to decrease the load of main network

Tags: mongodb, networking, sharding, network-traffic

I have created a 8 node MongoDB cluster with 2 shards + 2 Replica(1 for each shard) + 3 Config Servers + 1 Mongos.

All these are on network 192.168.1.*(eth0) with application server. So this network is handling all the traffic.
So I have created one another network 192.168.10.*(eth1) which is having only these 8 MongoDB nodes.

Now all the eight nodes are the part of both the networks with dual IP's.
Now I want to shift the internal traffic between these mongodb nodes to network 192.168.10.*(eth1) to reduce the load from main network 192.168.1.*(eth0)

So how to bind the ports/nodes for the purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution of the problem I was looking for. I configured the cluster according to the IP's of network 192.168.11.*_*
Now the internal data traffic is going through this network.

Answer (score 0):

You can use bind_ip as a startup or [configuration](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/configuration-options/) option. Keep in mind that various nodes need to be accessible in the event of failover.

Notably here is your single **mongos** where it would be advised to either co-locate the service per app server, or depending on requirements, have a **pool** available to your driver connection. Preferably both and having a **large** instance for each *'mongos'* where aggregate operations are used.

Comment: Hi Neil,Thanks for your response and suggestions. This was a test cluster so I will be adding more mongos nodes shortly as suggested by you.